# How to account for size of status bar in Xcode 5 storyboard?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

If I open my existing project that was created with XCode 4.6 with XCode 5 then my views and the status bar are overlapping in  the storyboard but they are not with XCode 4.6. There is presumably some setting in IB to include/exclude the status bar to fix this but I'm unable to find it. See screen shots below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into the [iOS 7 design guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174) and perhaps rethinking the custom effect. If you are set on using a custom background for your navigation and status bars then you will probably want to set it to 64 points tall in order to cover both the status bar and the nav bar.

Another option you have, which will allow you to continue more closely to how you've used it in the past, is to use to new `iOS 6/7 Deltas` feature. See [iOS 7 - Status bar overlaps the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view) for some great recommendations on how to handle this.