# Maintaining Backward compatibility iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

The question might sound silly but I guess it may be a matter of interest for many developers.
With the launch of Xcode-5 & development being targeted to iOS7, how do I maintain backward compatibility to make the app run properly on older versions of iOS ?

I see the big challenge with `UINavigationController`layout. With Navigation bar visible, the `CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)` will take the upper left corner just after Navigationbar but now in iOS-7, it goes behind. I know the solution to fix this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7), but how the same can work for older version when this feature is newly introduced.

What else places do I need to bridge this gap (the backward compatibility)

Comment: see this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view. In previous versions, you need to set the xib like this.

Comment: @karthika : I want to mention that I prefer working with Custom Views. So for, all that Drag/Drop/setting properties, I prefer writing codes. I was expecting some answer to keep backward compatibility via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `viewController.topLayoutGuide.length` instead of 0 in manual layout, [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_34).