# Viewcontroller looks ok in iOS 7 but shown under status bar in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiview, ios7

I am developing application which is compatible for iOS 6 and iOS 7. I am using xcode 5 for that.I have created one view for it. For iOS 7 view is looked fine but in iOS 6 my view is under the status bar. I have googled for this problem but couldn't find any success. I am uploading screen shot for it. Any help is appreciated.

iOS 6 screen shot:

[image]

iOS 7 screen shot:

[image]

Comment: refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view

Comment: @karthika:Thanks for the prompt response.Will refer it≥

Comment: @karthika: My problem is reverse.In got problem in iOS6.

Comment: have you modified any delta value?

Comment: @karthika:No i haven't.

Comment: Are you hiding your status bar on application launch? I think you might just need to reveal it earlier. Had a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue:

1. instead of using a ViewController, use a TableViewController
2. from the TableViewController delete the cell, and drop a simple view onto its tableView.
3. expand the view to match the tableView's frame
4. put all needed content in that view.

After this, the tableViewController will automatically adjust it's tableView right under the navigation bar as in IOS 7 as in 6.

Comment: Why would some one want to use tableVC when they need VC?.

Comment: A tableviewController is a subclass of ViewController. my approach is the fastest solution if you dont wanna play with the frames, just remove the cell, and put a uivew.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, i solve the problem creating a UIImageView inside status bar, and then inside add a UINavigationBar.

---

### UIImageView (320x20px)      x=0 y=0

UINavigationBar (320x44px)  x=0  y=20

---

Answer (score 0):

Although it's now deprecated, you could set `wantsFullScreenLayout` to `YES` for iOS 6.

Answer (score -2):

Make you navigation bar opaque. It will solve the problem.

Comment: what if you don't need it to be opaque, but still need not to go under it?