# ios 7 navigation bar too small

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar

I am trying to update my iPhone app to iOS7.

I am having major issues with the navigation bar. I would like it to have the new navigation bar.

As you can see from my image it has squashed the title to the top near the status bar.

I dont want to remove the status bar.

Surely it cant be that difficult to change.

I also noticed on some apps its changed automatically and on other apps it hasn't?

[image: My navigation bar which is squashed.]

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController or did you add a navigation bar to your view yourself?

Comment: I added the navigation bar my self. @FelixLam

Comment: if ios 7 then present  modal view controller,Then navigation controller as view controller

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: I just tried it, it didn't make it any larger :\ thank you though,

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Lots of people with similar issues, though. Have you tried using deltas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view

Answer (score 0):

You should try and do it the correct way by adding your view controller to a `UINavigationController` and use its `UINavigationBar`. This will handle most layout issues for you and will also be backwards compatible. If you post the code where you bring your ViewController on screen, we will gladly help to wrap it in a navigation controller.