# iOS7 Status Bar issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios7, statusbar

I have found many links for Status Bar issue in iOS 7 bt none of them helped much.

The issue is my application runs well in iOS6 but when I try to run it on iOS7, I want the iOS7 look and feel.

The status bar gels nicely with a `UIViewController` like below :
 [image: statusBar with UIVewController]

But for `UINavigationController` it goes black like below :
[image: statusBar with UINavigationController]

I managed to change the text-color of the statusBar using the following code in AppDelegate :

```
if ([[UIView appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) {
        [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
```

Also, my plist file has the following entry :
`View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `NO`

and my AppDelegate has :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

I want the statusBar to take the Blue color when a NavigationController is loaded.

NOTE : I have used the following code for iOS7 support :

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
#endif
```

Don't know if this caused the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to find the solution to your problem, but try using this guide, is really good:

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: The guide that you mentioned is really helpful but sadly doesn't help solve my issue...

Comment: Why did you accept it as an answer if it doesn't solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you use different images. One for iOS7 (20px higher) and one for the others and set this image as background for your navBar.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a good and explained answer here.

[Status bar and navigation bar issue in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-issue-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7/19025547#19025547)

and here

[iOS 7 - Status bar overlaps the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view)