# iOS 7 Status bar overlapping issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I tried the following suggested solution and it did move my screen down but the status bar becomes invisible (black). I also tried turning off view controller based status bar style in info.plist and then setStatusBarStyle in AppDelegate, but no luck, how can I get the status bar to display, please help..

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
    self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
    self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, self.window.frame.size.width,      self.window.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428712/ios7-status-bar-issue check it

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
       self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
       self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
else{
       self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
}
```

Please try using this.

Comment: Can't see the difference from my code and yours..as I said it's not working