# IOS7 all views are moved to the top of the screen

Tags: iphone, ios7, xib

I am just finally updating my app into IOS7. Seems like all of the XIBs now load to the very top of the screen and over write the Carrier, Time and Battery. Do I need to set something to move everything down?

Comment: Please clarify what has moved up. The xib itself or the elements in the view, or the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal if you are using iOS7. See this [Fix for status bar issue in IOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-issue-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7/19025547#19025547) or this [iOS 7 - Status bar overlaps the view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776211/2573134) (...problem already solved).

Comment: I dont know how they call this normal and why Apple would do this is beyond me. While it looks like a simple solution (above links) if you have a few XIBS I have 82 and messing with 82 xibs and then retesting the app so it hits every xib is crazy. Thank you apple.