# Status Bar Issue for Auto Layout in ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, statusbar

My apps contains various xibs, I am using Auto Layout to adjust view to support various devices. The problem is on iOS6 my views leaving 20 pixel distance for status bar, since this has changed in iOS7. I searched on net and came across approach that by adjusting delta we can overcome this issue, but this will not work when we use Auto Layout, and I do not want to change it through code so is there way to handle this issue using interface builder also?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You want to hide your status bar from your project ?????

Comment: At that edge of time still you are using xibs. Try to move on storyboard.

Comment: Actually in iOS6 status bar was 20 pixel and navigation bar was 44 pixel now in iOS7 (status bar + navigation bar) are 60 pixel combined and transparent also you you handle it by system version condition also...

Comment: @ParvendraKumar, Thanks for your reply but I don't want to handle it by coding.

Comment: this is helpful you 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view

Comment: this works for me. you are made duplicate question

[iOS7 Status bar issue ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7/19025547#19025547

Comment: @iDev, Thanks for your reply. But I am using the Auto Layout , so there is no option for setting Delta property in xib.