# Status Bar Issue for Auto Layout in ios sdk due to missing Delta Property

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, autolayout, statusbar

My apps `contains various xibs`**(Not Using StoryBoard)**, I am `using Auto Layout` to adjust view to support various devices.

**The problem is** on iOS6 my views leaving 20 pixel distance for status bar, since this has changed in iOS7. I searched on net and came across approach that by adjusting delta we can overcome this issue, but this will not work when we use Auto Layout, and I do not want to change it through code so is there way to handle this issue using interface builder also?
Thanks in advance!

I also searching for set the Edge Inset Uncheck but It is also not found in the Attribute Inspector Window as shown below.

**Is there any way to add a Top Layout Guide in xib?**

**What can I do for solve this?**

[image]

Comment: If you use delta values means whats is the output?

Comment: @Ganapathy, I am Using Auto-Layout & with this the delta property is unavailable.

Comment: You can't access the delta value if you use auto layout property.

Comment: @Ganapathy, I knew that but what is the alternative for this.

Comment: Then i think you can't fix it via interface builder. You need to handle the frame programmatically based on the IOS version that it.

Answer (score 0):

See these:

[iOS 7 status bar back to iOS 6 default style in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style)

[iOS 7 - Status bar overlaps the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+7+status+bar