# iOS 7 Retina Display Cuts top portion of Navigation Bar

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, xcode5, frame, statusbar

iOS 7 Retina Display Cuts top portion of Navigation Bar after simply viewing a YouTube video or go to a URL that streams music. The Navigation Bar remains cut of at the top through out the app. Almost looks like a thin black bar or a gap that cuts a small portion at the top and the best way I can explain it is if you see a navigation bar at the top of a an app, imagine that the top half of it is black.

Little info about Status bar in the app:
Status bar is initially hidden YES
View controller-based status bar appearance NO
Using Auto Layout

I would appreciate any help as this is really frustrating.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view

Comment: WOW! SIR I THANK YOU! Thank You so very much!!! There was an answer in that thread that I had not tried and it worked! Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
        self.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width,screenHeight-20);
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```