# iOS 7 navigation bar under status bar after show mail-sms composer

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar, ios7-statusbar

After upgrade my project to iOS7 my views showed under status bar.Later i fixed this issue by adding following code to DashBoardViewController's(Root navigation controller) viewdidAppear

```
float systemVersion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if(systemVersion>=7.0f)
{
    CGRect tmpFrame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
    tmpFrame.origin.y = 20;
    self.navigationController.view.frame = tmpFrame;
}
```

But in my SettingsViewController when i present modal view to show sms composer, after compose finished or cancelled that view under status bar again. But when back to DashBoardViewController view back to normal. I don't know what to do. I hope I could explain the problem. My codes and screenshots are below.

->ScreenShots:
[image]

### SettingViewController.m ( show SMS compose and finish compose methods)

```
- (IBAction)act_shareSMS:(id)sender {
    
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    NSString* message = @"adasdasd";
    controller.body =message;
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    
    if([NavigationManager sharedManager].contentNavigation)
        [[NavigationManager sharedManager].contentNavigation presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

    [[NavigationManager sharedManager].contentNavigation dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Message cancelled");
    } 
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent) {
       NSLog(@"Message sent");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this change is an intended change to iOS 7, this should help you with dealing with it http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/

try using the iOS 6/7 delta's on the viewcontrollers subviews to automatically fix this issue

[image]

set the delta Y to 20 and it should automatically move it down for you

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I try this but not works.The problem is after cancel or finished sms compose screen

Answer (score 0):

If you are supporting your app for io7 then I would request you to just read this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW2) and use the concept of "edgesForExtendedLayout". In that way you don't need to put that extra 20px. Just use "edgesForExtendedLayout" under your if.

Just have a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776211/1307844), and you are all set to go. Don't put anything in viewDidAppear, rather move it to viewDidLoad.

Hope this helps.