# UIViewcontroller in iOS 7 starting from top of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, ios6.1, ios7-statusbar

I have developed a app in `Xcode 5.1` for `iOS 6.1` and above.
I designed the View controllers from the top without leaving any margin. When I run this on `iOS 6.1`, it starts from below the top bar that indicates carrier and battery, but on `iOS 7` it overlaps the bar.

I searched and found that full screen was deprecated in `iOS 7` onwards. This was the code I found on many blogs that states that adding it to `viewDidLoad` will make the viewcontroller start from below the bar in IOS 7.0. But this is not working for me.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
```

Do I need to add something more. I want this app for iOS 6.1 and above and also for screen inches 3.5 and 4.

Comment: Side note - Do not check the system version like that. Instead you should check to see if the method exists: `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {`

Comment: This can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution for this. 
In main storyboard, select view as IOS 7 and later and add 20 delta to y to your view.
So when you run your app in IOS 7 and later, it will automatically add 20 offset to your view.It will have no offset added for IOS 6.1 and earlier.