# Application View moves up by 20 pixel on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios6

When I minimize and maximize app in iOS 6 whole application view moves up by 20 pixel. (looks like ignoring status bar) But on iOS 7 its ok because status bar is overlaid on the application view.

I don't want app view to be moved up.
Can anyone explain what's happening?

Comment: The height of the window frame is 20 pixels more in ios 7.  I'm not sure there is an easy fix. a fixed used can be to manipulate the window frame size depending if ios 6 or ios 7 by adding or subtracting from the frame height 20 pixels etc.  I can't give a complete solution but if you search there are some general status bar solutions particularly stuff orientated toward people migrating from ios 6 to ios 7.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is bad solution but I had no other way to do this :(
I just moved down main window by 20 pixel in applicationWillEnterForeground.
    `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        if(!iOS7)
            [self.window setY:20];
    }`
This works good now : )
Hope this helps anyone : )

Comment: Shame nobody else commented for scalable solution. I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

I checked "`Adjust Scroll View Insets`" in the *MainStoryboard* `Attributes Inspector` and it worked.

NOTE: I'm using a UITAbleView embedded in a Navigation Controller embedded in a tabViewController. I "selected" the main TabBarViewController.

The screen doesn't hide behind the header anymore.

This link helped a lot: [UITableView embedded in other view has wrong position of section header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430279/uitableview-embedded-in-other-view-has-wrong-position-of-section-header)