# Adding TabBar Pushes Cells and View Up [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

When I add a TabBar to my VC the cells in the view all move up, covering a part of the cell under the header.

Here is an image that shows the VC **without** the TabBar:

[image]

---

**This is with the TabBar:**

[image]

*(Don't mind the black screen/video screen please. Not relevant)*

When I scroll up when the TabBar is there, the "scroll/UIACtivityView" disappears as well. It loads, but it doesn't have an activity indicator.

I have to scroll up to see the picture where it shows the name "Selected"

Anyone know why the TabBar pushes up the whole view? If so, how do I prevent that?

Any help means a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a **TabViewController** and I checked "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in the MainStoryboard Attributes Inspector and it fixed the issue.

**(Select the TabViewController/Root View and THEN adjust Scroll View Insets)**

The cells/view don't hide behind the header anymore.

The `Adjust Scroll View Insets` definition:

```
"A boolean value that indicates whether the viewController should automatically adjust its scroll view insets."
```

I used this link as a reference:

[UITableView embedded in other view has wrong position of section header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430279/uitableview-embedded-in-other-view-has-wrong-position-of-section-header)

Hope that helps others!