# how to fix status bar overlap issue in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6, statusbar

I am developing an application that's working fine in IOS6. But in iOS7, the status bar overlaps with the view.

As an example :
[image: IOS7]

I need the status bar first, and *then* my icons and Remove last .So Please give me any idea about how to remove the overlap.

but I need this

[image]
Please  give me  any idea about my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 -(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) 
  {
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenHeight = 0.0;
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    else
        screenHeight = screenRect.size.width;
    CGRect screenFrame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width,screenHeight-20);
    CGRect viewFr = [self.view convertRect:self.view.frame toView:nil];
    if (!CGRectEqualToRect(screenFrame, viewFr))
    {
        self.view.frame = screenFrame;
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add this code into ur view controller, if u add progrmatically it working fine for u , if u used navigation bar use santhosh dharma code it will be fine for use xib or storybaord

Answer (score 5):

`Xcode` has iOS 6/7 Deltas which is specifically made to resolve this issue. You have to moved your views 20 pixels down to look right on iOS 7 and in order to make it iOS 6 compatible, You changed Delta y to -20.

[image]

Resize the height of views properly on iOS 6 You had to set Delta height as well as Delta Y.

You can see also this - [Fix iOS 7 Status bar overlapping](http://just-works.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-fix-ios-7-status-bar-overlapping_1350.html)

Comment: Sonthos Sharma thanks for Reply but i am not using  Story board.So Please give me any idea.How to solve this issue programmatically'

Comment: It can be do without storyboard. Open your .xib file remove autolayout check after that you can set your delta y.

Comment: You can see this answer also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.use this code in your AppDelegate.m in did finishlaunching:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
```

Comment: thanks for Reply i tried as you said but it's work on only MainViewControl view but remaining View not working So Please give me any idea

Comment: Check this link .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7

Comment: Can you check your UIViewController is embedded within a UINaivigationController.

Comment: i am not adding NaivigationController

Comment: ok.try like this add this to every viewcontroller to solve- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
  self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);}

Comment: This will break horribly when rotating your device, if your app supports it.

Answer (score -1):

This is the default behavior for UIViewController on iOS 7. The view will be fullscreen and the status bar will cover the top of the view. If you have navigationBar hidden, then you have to adjust all the UIView elements by shifting 20 points.