# PresentModalViewController overlaps the navigation bar and status bar iOS 7

Tags: ios7, xcode5.1, uimodalpresentationstyle

I resolved the navigation bar status bar issue in all my views, but when I use presentModalViewController to show another view, navigation bar and status bar overlaps again.I am  using this for presenting new view:

```
[self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

Any idea to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
1.your viewcontroller

```
UIViewController *View=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
```

2.If u need Navigation bar add this code

```
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:View];

nav.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;(presentingModal view)

[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Check this link and refer my answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781169/how-to-fix-status-bar-overlap-issue-in-ios-7/25781823#25781823 and also check this link too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by

1. pushing the navigation bar and other views by 20 pixels for the view that i was presenting as modal view controller
2. setting the black color background for status bar in viewDidload by:

   ```
   UIView *statusBarView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 20)];
   statusBarView.backgroundColor  =  [UIColor blackColor];
   [self.view addSubview:statusBarView];
   ```