# Status bar overlaps on my view

Tags: ios, uistatusbar, ios7-statusbar

I have a `UIViewController` subclass which when I run the app on iOS 7, the status bar shows on top of my view. Is there a way to avoid this? I do not want the status bar to be hidden. Is there a way to show the status bar above my app. I present my view using `presentViewController`. Please guide what I am missing?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781169/how-to-fix-status-bar-overlap-issue-in-ios-7/25884064#25884064

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

Comment: I used the below code to lower my view 20 px down..it worked fine for portrait orientation but fails for landscapeif ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        if(self.view.frame.origin.y == 0) {
            CGRect viewBounds = [self.view bounds];
            viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
            viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 20;
            self.view.frame = viewBounds;
        }
    }

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19522409/2835520)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 status bar back to iOS 6 default style in iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-default-style-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, In storyboard there is an option of iOS6/7 delta. set delta Y to 20 pixel of your view, to make compatible with iOS7.For this you have to disable auto layout, you can use auto resizing. [image: see the attached image]

Comment: I want auto layout on my view

Comment: sorry i do not want auto layout on my view

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common issue. Starting from iOS 7 Status Bar is a part of the controller's view. Apple even have added special attribute of UIView in the Interface Builder: **iOS 6/7 Deltas**.  To fix your problem and make your view look the same in different iOS versions, go to Size inspector and set Delta Y to 20.0.

Comment: am not able to set deltas as I am using auto layout on my view

Comment: In this case you should add a constraint and change its value programmatically according to iOS version.

Comment: can u tell me how to set status bar above my view programatically for iOS 7 for both portrait and landscape orientations using auto layout