# iOS 7,8 XCODE 6.2 XIB Layout using Layout Editor and Auto Layout, View is on top of Status Bar

Tags: ios, xib, statusbar

Looked around and could not find a solution (non code) for this.

XCode 6.2, iOS 7,8 XIB file layout with Auto Layout.  When this is view is presented, it is on top of / over the status bar.

Everything looks good in the XIB Editor, the view is set at 20 for Y, but when presented it seems to ignore this setting, putting the view right on top of the status bar (blended).

This is a regular XIB file, not a storyboard.  Have tried many / most of the settings for status bar, etc.

The editor looks like this...

[image]

The runtime looks like this

[image]

Comment: I think you need to constrain the view to the top layout guide? Or try checking the Under Top Bars in the Extend Edges section.

Comment: Thanks but this does not exist in a non-storyboard xib file, or am I missing something here.

Comment: This SO questions has answers which relate to xibs it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781169/how-to-fix-status-bar-overlap-issue-in-ios-7. Looks like you have to turn auto layout off and then a DeltaY control lets you set the offset to 20.

Comment: Thanks , but the whole idea is to use Auto Layout for this screen.  Will try the code solution and see if it works.

Comment: If you do not have a UINavigationController, try embedding one in before this controller or add this controller via a UINavigationController. Aparently that should sort things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried a bunch of code solutions, none worked with Auto Layout.  Ended up putting a 20 space on top constraint of the Nav Bar in the Editor which looks wrong, but when run, looks correct.

Editor

[image]

Running

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks trying to find a solution that does not require code.  But if we have to ....

Comment: Tried it, does not work in ViewDidLoad when presenting this view with Auto Layout.