# What is the best way to correct the status bar overlaps in iOS 8?

Tags: ios

What is the best way to correct the status bar overlaps problem on iOS 8 in SWIFT ?

I've been checking this feed : [how to fix status bar overlap issue in ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781169/how-to-fix-status-bar-overlap-issue-in-ios-7)

and other various threads but it seems like the ios 6/7 Delta option does not exist anymore.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes I'm using storyboard

Comment: With not being sure, maybe the navigation bar is not at below of the battery icon