# How to move content of webview below status bar ios

Tags: ios, statusbar, nib

I'm converting an app to iOS 7/8, and one of the issues is that the primary page, which displays web content, has lettering which overlaps with the status bar. Is there a way to add a transparent element, maybe a label or an image, that will nudge the web view down so there's no overlap?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view

Answer (score 0):

Add a top constraint to your web view or main container view which is pinned to the top layout guide and not the top of the view.

That should cause it to stop before the status bar. When a navigation bar is shown, it should stop at the navigation bar.