# A white bar below my app after Xcode 5 upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

As iOS7 and xcode 5 is out, I am assuming we can talk about them. Today I upgraded to XCode 5 and suddenly on my mapView.xib I see a white bar below. I did not touch the xib file, what exactly is going on here and how I can fix it.

[image: View from Interface Builder]

Comment: That's because of a transparent status bar, I guess.

Comment: The view is still messed up with the white bar but I got the app working properly by suggestion provided in post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry. You'll have lots of fun re-adjusting your layouts. Some of the components dimensions changed drastically and probably you'll need to re-adjust windows and UIViews too.

Comment: Do I need to have two xib now ? one for ios6 and one for 7 ?

Comment: No, just the same (only one), but you need to fine tune what is showing wrongly. Very soon, most users will be using 7 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of structure of iOS 7, To resolve this issue select your background UIImageView in xib and apply following Autoresizing mask

[image]

After that create new imageSet with name "iOS7bgImg" and add device support [iPhone & iPhone 4-inch] and add respective images in a boxes with following resolutions.

```
320 * 480

640 * 960

640 * 1136
```

[image]

create a IBOutlet of backgroundImage view

Now check programmatically

if(iOS 7)
{

[Setup new image in your background]

}

That's it solve.

Answer (score 0):

Open the xib and set the frame of the view of this view controller to the screen frame. In iOS7 the status bar is translucent and your view also is behind it. Therefore your view has to be 20 px taller to fill the screen.

Comment: Please help me with little bit more explanation. How can I set the frame of view to screen frame ?

Comment: I think it's in the attribute inspector of the interface builder.