# After updating to iOS 7 all views in iOS 6 moved up and are hidden by the navigation bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I have updated my iPhone to iOS 7 today and recompile my app for it and all views in .xib files and on device are moved up and their upper part is hidden by the navigation bar. In my `viewController` I set  `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` and on iOS 7 now everything looks good but when I compile my project with Deployment Target 6.0 and tested it on iOS 6 device all views are hidden by the navigation bar again.How can I make them to look consistently on iOS 7 and iOS 6 simultaneously? I don't want to break iOS 6 support now.

Comment: I have answered this question at length here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style/18855464#18855464

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So here is what I did. It's not the cleanest code ever and you need to make sure you don't get weird results with your scroll views.

Basically I move down all of the subviews by the height of the navbar (45). For my scrollviews/tableviews, which in my app always go to the bottom of the screen, I reduce their height by 45 so that you can still reach the end. This is a solution for some apps, but you should make sure that all of your scroll and tableviews are intended to be shrunk like this.

Because it's not recursive, you don't need to worry about tableviews in scrollviews or anything like that.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {

        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    } else {
        [self moveAllSubviewsDown];
    }

}

- (void) moveAllSubviewsDown{
    float barHeight = 45.0;
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {

        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y + barHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height - barHeight);
        } else {
            view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y + barHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the following code in your *.pch file too.... #define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

Comment: You can also check iOS version using if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)

Answer (score 16):

Try using:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Storyboards in Interface Builder with Autolayout, you can add a constraint for the top of your view with the "Top Layout Guide"

Comment: This worked for me. As explanation: The "Top Layout Guide" should be used as reference to layout your views relative to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Interface Builder, I've had some luck with unchecking the setting for "extend  edges" > "under top bars":

[image]

Works for me in iOS 7 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

Add this value to your app plist: "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to "NO".

Comment: Have you tried to set the bar in your code? for example hidden? what exactly doesn't work?