# uiview appears distorted in ios7 but works fine for ios6 and others

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

`UIView` of my app appears fine in ios6 but when it comes to ios7 the entire view is distorted. In ios7 the whole view is lifted upwards.

**EDIT** :

Then I applied this code:

```
float SystemVersion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if(SystemVersion<7.0f)
{

    //Currently your app is running in IOS6 or older version. So you need not to do     anything.

}
else
{
    // Currently your app is running in IOS7. Do the following.

    CGRect TempRect;
    for(UIView *sub in [[self view] subviews])
    {
        TempRect=[sub frame];
        TempRect.origin.y+=20.0f; //Height of status bar
        [sub setFrame:TempRect];
    }
}
```

but still there is no change. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Try this way..

[IOS & DISPLAY][1]


OR 

This..

[Status Bar Issue][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19042940/1673099
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158325/status-bar-issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894541/after-updating-to-ios-7-all-views-in-ios-6-moved-up-and-are-hidden-by-the-naviga

Comment: I got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

[IOS & DISPLAY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19042940/1673099)

OR

This..

[Status Bar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158325/status-bar-issue)

This way make the your All subviews as +20 pixels i.e.Increase the +20 of y-axis for all views 
`Set the deleta` for the ios 7. so, it will display the good in both ios 6 & 7.

Answer (score 0):

//Give it frame  if navigation bar and status bar both displaying on screen
// first check if device have ios 7
 `if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))

   {

      self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,64,320,self.view.height);

   }`

Answer (score 0):

try my answer...write that code in ViewdidLoad method..

[Status Bar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158325/status-bar-issue/19158433#19158433)

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: i've applied your code.but its not working.i ll send u the screen shot if u give ur mail id.

Comment: it needs 10+ reputation .i jus startd stack overflow today only.. :)

Comment: sorry nirav am not allowed to share screen shot.it appears like navigation bar is hidden inside status bar.but view has come little down

Answer (score 0):

Please see below note

Using xcode 5,

click on xib,Go to file inspector and change setting as below

Deployment target as ios 7

here,You need to crate two xib view based on view as ios 7 and later and view as ios 6 and earlier and white condition based on xib call

Define below code in .m file

**#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)**

if view as IOS 7.0 and later

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))

```
 //Here call ios 7 xib
```

}else{

```
 //Here call ios 6 and earlier xib
```

}

Answer (score -2):

You have to create two xib for ios6 and ios7.

than You have to check condition if device is of ios7 than call ios7 xib otherwise go for ios6.