# Changing the status bar text color in splash screen iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, splash-screen, statusbar, uistatusbar

I know that are already some [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7) that say how to change the status bar for all view controllers. I am currently changing the color of status bar this way:

```
if(IS_IOS7)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

In the `application:DidFinishLaunching`

Additionally, I have changed the value of `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` in the plist to `NO`. However, in the splashscreen it stills shows the status bar text with the black color.

Is it possible to change the color of the status bar text color **in the splash screen**?

Comment: What do you mean 'it still shows the status bar with the black color' : If your code works, status bar font should be white, status bar background color depends on your splash image (which should now include status bar height - 20 pixels)

Comment: Sorry, I really missed the text word. I am changing only the text color of the status bar. I can change it after the splash screen happens but I can't change it when the splash screen is happening.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

In the project plist file add the "Status Bar Style" property (key is `UIStatusBarStyle`).  Then ignore all the possible values listed in the drop down for this property and type `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` instead.

And you don't have to set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`to `NO`in your plist, you can set the `preferredStatusBarStyle` you want to your view controllers.

Comment: Is there any way to make this compatible with a tinted status bar on iOS 6 ?

Comment: Text color of status bar is either white, or black. The background of the bar comes from your launch image, then from your viewController's view if it extends below bars.

Comment: After TONS of different methods, this one FINALLY worked (with UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance set to NO). You are a hero.

Comment: you can also do this via code UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent. I do it in AppDelegate

Comment: @Yasmin : to changer color AFTER the splash screen, this solution was already part of the question ;)

Comment: I have UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance set to YES and it doesn't work. iOS 8.4 Xcode 6.4. I really need to set that to YES in my project.

Answer (score 33):

**You can do this without writing any line of code** 

Do the following to make the status bar text color white through the whole app

On you **project plist** file:

- Status bar style: `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`
- View controller-based status bar appearance: `NO`
- Status bar is initially hidden: `NO`

Comment: The accepted answer is good, but it didn't work on all my view controllers without doing the 2nd bullet above. Thanks!

Comment: "View controller-based status bar appearance: `YES`" still seems to do the trick (iOS 9)

Answer (score 19):

You can do the following things for getting light color status bar throughout the application.

1. Select the name of the project in the project navigator.
2. Select the name of a target from the list in the left column of the project editor.
3. Click General at the top of the project editor.
4. Set Status Bar Style -> Light

In your plist file add the following values:

1. Status bar style -  UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
2. View controller-based status bar appearance -  NO

This will help you to get the status bar in WHITE colour throughout the application including SPLASH SCREEN.

Answer (score 7):

Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to No in the plist

Then add the following code in did finish launch option

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {

   [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;

    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
```

Please follow this code it worked for me

Comment: this is showing white text on status bar while my background is also light. how can I show black text

Comment: Mangesh on the Target go to the general settings there you will have a option to set the status bar style

Comment: You could actually write that first line a little bit simpler using dot syntax, like this:

`if (UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion.floatValue >= 7) {`

Answer (score 2):

Here is [Apple Guidelines/Instruction](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/) about status bar change.

*Here is - How to change status bar style:*

If you want to set status bar style, application level then set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in your `.plist' file.

if you wan to set status bar style, at view controller level then follow these steps:

1. Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `.plist` file, if you need to set status bar style at UIViewController level only.
2. In the viewDidLoad add function - `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`
3. override preferredStatusBarStyle in your view controller.

-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Set value of .plist according to status bar style setup level.
[image]

You can set background color for status bar during application launch or during viewDidLoad of your view controller.

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

}

// Set upon application launch, if you've application based status bar
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return true
    }
}


or 
// Set it from your view controller if you've view controller based statusbar
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following things for getting light color status bar throughout the application.

Select the name of the project in the project navigator.
Select the name of a target from the list in the left column of the project editor.
Click General at the top of the project editor.
Set Status Bar Style -> Light