# How to set status bar's content color to white on iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios7

My App’s background colour is black. Cause the whole view is below the status bar on iOS 7, the content on the status bar will hard to be distinguished. So how to change status bar’s content colour to white?

I've tried `preferredStatusBarStyle` and several other ways, but failed.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

1. Set "View controller-based status bar appearance” to **NO** in your **info.list** file;
2. Insert

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
   ```

   to `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of the AppDelegate.m.

---

**Note**: `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` is the default value for the status bar style, it'll show black content instead. Both `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent` & `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` are deprecated in iOS 7.0.

---

#### UPDATE for iOS 9:

As [@ZakariaDarwish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953879/how-to-set-status-bars-content-color-to-white-on-ios-7/18953880?noredirect=1#comment64007521_18953880) mentioned, the method `-setStatusBarStyle` is deprecated in iOS 9. (Note: The original question was asked for iOS 7 long time ago, and I don't support it now, the new solution below works for me under iOS 9, hence update here.)

So, the only way left (*at least for now*) is to implement `-preferredStatusBarStyle` in your view controller (remember to set "View controller-based status bar appearance" back to **YES**).

You can invoke UIViewController's instance method `-setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` once value changed in `-preferredStatusBarStyle` or `-prefersStatusBarHidden`.

There're also two methods `-childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle` & `-childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden` to return the preferred style from child view controller as you want.

**e.g.**, if you used below methods

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

to switch status bar style before, you can use code sample below

```
- (void)shouldChangeStatusBarStyleToLightContent:(BOOL)toLightContent
                                        animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  _shouldChangeStatusBarStyleToLightContent = toLightContent;
  if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3f animations:^{ [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]; }];
  } else {
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
  }
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
  return (_shouldChangeStatusBarStyleToLightContent ? UIStatusBarStyleLightContent : UIStatusBarStyleDefault);
}
```

for this updated solution now.

Comment: Only a tip: You can use application instead of [UIApplication sharedApplication] if you are setting this in -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: Works on iOS 8.2, too.

Comment: Note: because `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not called until the application loads, this will *not* change the color of the status bar on the launch screen.

Comment: To also impact the launch screen, use the .plist method instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18898750/111243

Answer (score 70):

In your *-Info.plist file:

1. Set 'View controller-based status bar appearance' to NO
2. Set 'Status bar style' to UIStatusBarStyleLightContent

Alternatively you can specify Status bar style as 'Black Opaque' or 'Black Translucent' in General tab of the Target.(in Xcode 5.0.1) But they are obsoleted values.

Comment: Outstanding, and greatly appreciated. With the deprecation of setStatusBarStyle in iOS 9.0, this is an absolute godsend.

Answer (score 26):

I use this in main controller:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Place these two keys in **info.plist**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**Here a short and simple solution to set status bar color White**

1) First copy this line `View controller-based status bar appearance` to  in your .plist file and set Boolean `NO`;

2) In your **AppDelegate.m** file under **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** paste this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

**OR add in .plist**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

iOS 9 (deprecated warning workaround)

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    #ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
    # define STATUS_STYLE UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
    #else
    # define STATUS_STYLE UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent
    #endif

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:STATUS_STYLE animated:YES];
```

Comment: That's only a compile-time decision, though — not a run-time decision.

Answer (score 5):

If your application have different status bar's content color for each view controller the preferred method would be implementing

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

If you need to change the bar's content color globally throughout the application then add following lines of code in your **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        return true
    }
```

Wait setting the statusBarStyle does nothing if your application is using the default UIViewController-based status bar system. For this

**Set "View controller-based status bar appearance” to NO in your info.list file**

Answer (score 4):

Just a note, since this was there. If you are using a UINavigationController, you can throw this into the view controllers `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

Comment: This is wrong! `barStyle` is of type `UIBarStyle` which does not have `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

Comment: Yeah it seems to work regardless. I understand it does not have the property in the class description but it seems to convert the UIBarStyle to UIStatusBarStyle for whatever reason. You can test it yourself in one line of code...

Comment: @Shawn these enums are both of NSInteger type, this is why it doesn't yell an error. If you'll enable all warnings in build settings ,this will become a warning due to type mismatch.

Comment: @art-divin do you know why even with the warning it follows through with my intended use?

Comment: @shawn it works because the status bar inherits a bunch of settings from the UINavigationBar and adjusts accordingly. So color, transparency, text and content in the status bar will be adjusted based on the UIBarStyle. I found a really good [write up here](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/).

Answer (score 2):

To do it programmatically in Swift 3 try this anywhere in your view controller.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
  }
```

I also set the plist key "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES.