# layout issues when building an old app in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xib

I am making some changes in an old app that is not be worked on for more then 2 years. I've build and run the app in xCode 6 and got the following result.

[image]

For the status bar i'm trying the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
    {
        [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS 6
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
}

// Add this method
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Also I'm trying to set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to NO

Can anybody help me with this? I'm not using storyboards and not planning to do with this app. It are all seperated XIB files.

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT**

After adding this code:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
```

I get the following:
[image]

My tabbar is created in code in my appdelegate:

```
 self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeNavigation,bookNavigation,doctorsNavigation,settingsNavigation,locatorNavigation,nil];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Have you tried setting status bar setting in .plist file?

Comment: @the_UB if you mean View controller-based status bar appearance, then YES :)

Comment: Since you have not provide any code about what you did to resolve this issue, check this similar issue [how to fix status bar overlap issue in ios 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781169/how-to-fix-status-bar-overlap-issue-in-ios-7).

Comment: Try the solution given in the above link.

Comment: Now you have to set the status bar color. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897362/changing-the-status-bar-text-color-in-splash-screen-ios-7#).

Comment: Oh I see ,your tab bar is slightly disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to start the view controller below the status bar (write this code in `viewDidLoad` method).

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

and if you want to hide the status bar follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17768797/3733561)