# Force dark status bar text color on splash screen iOS 8

Tags: ios

My project's plist file has a flag **View controller-based status bar appearance = NO** (this is required by my app specifics).

And I tried to set **Status bar style** to **Gray style (default)** and **Opaque black style**.

But in both cases I get a white status bar text and so it's invisible on a white splash screen.

Is there any way to force the status bar text to black color on splash screen?

I've searched through the other questions like this, but found only setting the status bar text color to white:
[Changing the status bar text color in splash screen iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897362/changing-the-status-bar-text-color-in-splash-screen-ios-7).
And the solution proposed there doesn't seem to work for setting the color to black, at least for iOS 8.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the General Project Settings screen, there is a "Hide Status Bar" option. Please be sure that it is **unchecked**.
After that, open the LaunchScreen.xib file and select the view, in the Simulated Metrics section, if you select Default, it should show black status bar.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I don't use xib or storyboard for my main window, it's created programmatically.
And of course **Hide Status Bar** flag is unchecked, actually the status bar is visible, but with white text (I can see the green battery icon).