# How to change the tint color of navigation controller of LaunchScreen

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change the tint color of the navigation controller of the **Launchscreen** to white

I'm trying to add that code to my `AppDelegate`, it's working on all ViewControllers except for the LaunchScreen:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

the tint color is black, I want to change it to white.

[image]

Comment: do you mean to say status bar color?

Comment: Check this link it will really help you man. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897362/changing-the-status-bar-text-color-in-splash-screen-ios-7>

Comment: I initially misunderstood your question, so check out my [edited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35602314/3947107), it's very easy to change the status bar color.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a `UINavigationBar`, that is a `UIStatusBar`. Use

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

(cf. [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/statusBarStyle), deprecated in iOS 9)

For iOS 9, View Controllers decide this 'themselves', so whatever view controller is instantiated for your splash screen storyboard should override

```
func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle
```

and return `.LightContent`. (cf. [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/preferredStatusBarStyle))

Comment: Also, there seems not to be any NavigationController.

Comment: What is the easiest way to set the color *app wide*? Is setting the plist value as seen in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35602314/3947107) 'deprecated' as well?

Comment: Use a base class you inherit from in all other view controllers that implements this.

Comment: But the usage of that plist key can't be considered deprecated, right? (can't find related info in Apple's [iOS Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1)). So isn't that the easiest way to globally set the color?

Comment: It would be, if you could set it in iOS 9 using `statusBarStyle`, but I couldn't find a way to do so. Yet, depending on your code base, it's no big deal to insert an implementation for that in a base class and derive from e.g. `UIStatusBarViewController` instead of `UIViewController`

Comment: What do you mean? Doesn't it say: "UIStatusBarStyle, 
“Status bar style”, 
Specifies the style of the status bar as the app launches. See [UIStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW14) for details."

Comment: I See; we were talking about different keys. Then: give it a try; should work.

Answer (score 0):

## Setting status bar color *app wide*

If you want to set the color of the status bar *app wide* (in the launch screen as well) you should add this to your `info.plist` (right click > *Add row*):

`Status bar style = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`

---

More information about this key from Apple's [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1)

- **Key**: `UIStatusBarStyle`
- **Xcode name**: `Status bar style`
- **Value**: `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` = white, `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` = black
- **Summary**: Specifies the style of the status bar as the app launches. See [UIStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW14) for details.

Comment: This does not influence the status bar, does it?

Comment: So why are you suggesting this then? It's clear from the screenshot and the description that OP misnamed the status bar, see my answer.

Comment: Oh okay I see, OP wants white text in the status bar. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: There is no navigationController. So this will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Set these properties in Info.plist file
[image]

Add this

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that easily is through the Xcode UI:

Your App -> Targets -> General Tab

For a dark app background. You can use the "Light Content" mode.

[image]