# iPad landscape mode showing black bar in iOS7

Tags: ios7, landscape, xcode5

When my app stars in landscape mode, a black bar (the same size and position as the dock) appears and my app gets cut and it never goes away when i rotate the device.
It worked fine in iOS 6 and i can't find any solution.

Comment: can you attach a screen shot?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just needed to readjust de resizing masks.

Comment: could you please be more specific?

Comment: "readjust de resizing masks" isn't helpful; we don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

For apps with screen rotation,

use NSNotificationCenter to detect orientation changes by adding

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(applicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation:)
name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
object:nil];
in if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
```

and create a new method

```
- (void)applicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
    int a = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey: UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey] intValue];
    int w = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    int h = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    switch(a){
        case 4:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,w,h);
            break;
        case 3:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(-20,0,w-20,h+20);
            break;
        case 2:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,-20,w,h);
            break;
        case 1:
           self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(20,0,w-20,h+20);      
    }
}
```

in AppDelegate

so that when orientation changes, it will trigger a switch statement to detect app's screen orientation (Portrait, Upside Down, Landscape Left, or Landscape Right) and change app's window frame respectively to create the iOS 6 status bar illusion.

This is referenced @ [iOS 7 status bar back to iOS 6 default style in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style)

---

> Alternatively:

---

If you are using Storyboards (iOS 5+) and don't want your view controllers to be overlapped by the status bar (and navigation bars), deselect the "Extend Edges Under Top Bars" box in Xcode 5.0 IB Storyboard.

[image: uncheck the Extend Edges Under Top Bars]

Comment: thanks but a found a a simpler way. Just needed to readjust de resizing masks. ;)