# iOS 7 - adjusting for status bar

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autolayout, ios7

I am having trouble determining how to adjust for the status bar in iOS7. My view controller has a `tableView`, and I want the `tableView` to start under the status bar. Currently, it is being overlapped by the status bar. (The label at the top is a `headerView` in the `tableView`).

[image]

I have set the properties on my view controller via IB as follows:

```
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES
edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone
```

[image]

Is the expected behavior for these settings for the status bar to overlap the tableView? Or am I missing something? I have tried enabling auto-layout, and changing the project settings to only support iOS 7.

Comment: You can achieve iOS 6 like status bar in iOS 7

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style/19044681#19044681

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to check "Under Top Bars" and "Under Opaque Bars" in the Extend Edges section of IB.

Comment: What if I have a custom label? It doesn't seem to include those in the calculation.

Comment: how to deal with a xib file? (not storyboard)

Comment: I am using xcode 6 and storyboard. I checked "Under Top Bars" and "Under Opaque Bars", but my table view still overlaps with the status bar. I tried a couple of combinations of these 3 options, nothing works for me.