# Best way to fix iOS7 status bar issue using autolayout

Tags: ios7, autolayout

As of now we are all aware of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar)

I want to fix this issue using `autolayout`. Answers  that i found till only states about the delta that is in only avaliable with `autoresizing`

What is the best way to handle this issue in `autolayout` , i am using storyboard.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939071/ios-7-adjusting-for-status-bar) is not working for me

Comment: I m also facing this issue

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view

Comment: @karthika Thanks for reply but if we use `autolayout` it doesn't give us option of `iOS 6/7 Deltas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give in and embed it in a navigation controller, even if it is the only item.  Kind of strange to have a title, but you can think of it as keeping the user oriented.

Comment: But i am using `imageview` instead of `navigation controller` , and i have hide navigation controller

Comment: Your linked issue referenced a UITableViewController and embedding it in a navigation controller is valid solution.  Please update your question to describe exactly what the issue is with your views and the status bar and what the desired outcome is.

Answer (score 3):

Use the topLayoutGuide property of your view controller:

```
id top = self.topLayoutGuide;
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_sessionView, top);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[top][_sessionView(==50)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```