# StatusBar bug in iOS7?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, layout, ios7, uistatusbar

I have been stumpted by the fact that apple is making the StatusBar Overlay the viewController...or the bounds of my application. Is there a way i can move the TitleBar down in the StoryBoard? or do i have to guess where to place it? I am confused on what to do, now that the move to iOS7 has come. Here is my TitleBar in the application and in the Storyboard:

[image]

and:

[image]

How am i supposed to make this work? This is what i would like it to look like, without the green, but black. [image]

I even tried what is in this post, but nothing helped. [iOS 7 - adjusting for status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939071/ios-7-adjusting-for-status-bar)

Comment: I don't meant to be rude, but my rough estimation is that in the last month 50% of StackOveflow question are about the status bar in iOS 7. Search in SO and Google and you will find tons of answers, tutorials, explanations and even the official UI Transition Guide by Apple.

Comment: For instance these are all the questions tagged [tag:ios7] with the word "status bar". http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios7%5D+status+bar They are 585 and counting. Have you tried going through the most voted?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to read the document "iOS 7 UI Transition Guide". The simplest way to not let the status bar overlap the content of your view is to have a 20px high view sitting at the top of the view. That way your content won't move behind the statusbar. That being said, if you are using the UINavigationController as your "TitleBar", you shouldn't even need to add the 20px view, as the navigationcontroller takes care of it for you. All of this is in the "iOS 7 UI Transition Guide".

EDIT. For your information (or for anyone else who's struggling with this) I highly recommend looking at the "Customizing Your App’s Appearance for iOS 7" video from WWDC 2013. It is so comprehensive that it will pretty much solve all your iOS 7 UI problems.

Comment: -1 There's already tons of information about the subject. Your answer is not adding any value and it would be more beneficial to the OP if you just link to that questions in a comment (since you don't have enough privileges to cast a close vote)

Comment: I understand your concern Gabriele, but my attempt was sincerely to point the OP in the right direction as the question does show that the OP made attempts to look at previous questions of the same nature on SO. I specifically edited and added the WWDC 2013 video reference as it helped me tremendously. Would you rather have me delete this answer and post it as a comment to the question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I believe it would be more beneficial is  for you to link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7 and if you feel like the WWDC 2013 video helped you, you can either propose an edit to the accepted answer, comment on it or just post your own answer there. Scattering the information is not helpful in my opinion.

Comment: It is. And that's what I'm trying to do as well, just on a larger scale. This topic is sooo common, that a tremendous amount of people will come to StackOveflow looking for help. Scattering good pieces of information around several duplicate questions can maybe help the single OPs, but it's surely going to hurt future visitors. So, again, thanks for helping, your answer is correct, but there's something better that can be done.