# UINavigationBar showing a black background on the UIStatusBar even when using a 44p image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I've seen the Apple video where it explains that if you provide a `44p image` for the `UINavigationBar` it will just set the background for that.

I've also search around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style/18855464#18855464) very useful post and What I am experiencing is his point number `#5`. Where even tho I've supplied the 44p image I sill see the status bar with a black background.

I was just wondering... if anyone has been able to find a work around so that the status bar is transparent showing the `UIView Background`?, I've tried everything I could think of and came across by but nothing seems to work.

I set the background view in my `appDelegate`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BlackBackground"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**This is how it looks**

[image]

**This is how i want it to look**

[image]

Comment: In iOS7 status bar background is provided by your app. There are some ways you can control it. You should refer to the documentation.

Comment: try for transparent, [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];