# How to set status bar right in iOS 7

Tags: ios7

In iOS 7.0 status bar **UIStatusBarStyleBlack** is deprecated. My app uses Background image in the view. Image is extended behind the status bar(oddly) . How can I fit my View within the bounds. Much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 status bar back to iOS 6 style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 7.0, UI statusbar is transparent, To accommodate the changes in the app as with the status bar style you can use:

```
UIStatusBarStyleDefault
```

for Status bar to be dark while for light content use

```
  UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
```

If facing trouble with background image of View in app where the image is extending itself behind the status bar. Set the image in nib or programmatically(whichever suits you) explicitly with the dimensions on Image.

For More References on UI Changes refer this Guide by Apple.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/TransitionGuide.pdf