# UIViewController without NavigationBar, UIView overlaps with Status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I am working on updating my app to support `iOS7`, however one of my view is overlapping with the status bar. Please refer my image,

[image]

Apple recommends us to use, `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` to avoid fullscreen layout. however this is working when we have `UIViewController` within a `UINavigationController` and the navigationBar is visible.  In my app, I didn't use the `UINavigationController`. can anyone help me to solve this overlapping issue on UIViewController without NavigationBar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I myself found the answer. We need to offset the frame in 
`- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews` method as like follow,

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    {
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 20;
        frame.size.height = frame.size.height - 20;
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Since I am ofSetting the frame in `- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, user will not see the transition.  If we offset the frame in `-(void) viewDidload`, user will see the transition.  Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set `wantsFullScreenLayout = YES` somewhere on ViewController?

Comment: No, I haven't set. Also wantsFullScreenLayout = YES is deprecated in iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

Just offset your view in viewDidLoad:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.y = 20;
self.view.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Status bar style doesn't cause this issue.  The style of the status bar refers to the appearance of its content, which includes items such as time, battery charge, and Wi-Fi signal.

Comment: See edit then. Or check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style/18855464#18855464

Comment: What does no luck mean? Does it not work, as this is the only solution to offset your frame.

Comment: No luck means, it doesn't work. do you know any other code to offset the frame? if so post it here...

Comment: Try changing this line frame.y += 20; instead. Also try moving to viewWillAppear this should work, step through it

Comment: This is not working even after moving the code to viewWillAppear. So I moved this code to viewDidAppear and it changes the frame origin, however user is able to see this transition.

Comment: you should be offsetting the frame in the viewDidload. If you do this and then log out the frame what does it log out, is the change made? Can you provide more information than no luck or doesn't work. What investigation have you done?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a full explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18855464/1078579

The short answer is there's no way to prevent the status bar from overlapping your application on iOS 7. `edgesForExtendedLayout` only affects the child view controllers inside a UINavigationController or UITabBarController.

You'll need to move the contents of your app into a (0,20,320,548) container view if you want to preserve the iOS 6 style layout.

Answer (score -1):

Add following code in ViewDidLoad

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
 {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
 }
```

Comment: It won't work when there is no navigation bar.  it will work only when navigation bar is visible.