# How to change status bar color in iOS7?

Tags: ios7, uiappearance, uistatusbar

How can I change color of status bar while launch screen is showing? It's black while app is loading, but I need white.

Comment: visit this link, hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style.