# Show status bar in splash screen in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Is it possible to simulate iOS 6 status bar during application launch time (splash screen) in iOS 7? Basically I need to shift down the splash screen in iOS 7 on application launch time so the status bar is on the black background.

Comment: check it here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style/18855464#18855464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. You can specify different launch images for iOS 7 that have black line of 40 pixels height at the top (simulating the status bar). To do that, there are 2 possibilities:

1) Using Xcode inside General settings of your app. Specify different launch screens for iOS 7 by specifying  "Retina" and "Retina 4-inch" images.

[image]

2) Using plist. Set [UILaunchImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW28).

From [UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide):

> In iOS 7, an app can use a different launch image depending on which
>   version of iOS it’s running in. To provide different launch images,
>   add the UILaunchImages key to the Info.plist file and use a dictionary
>   to describe each launch image.More information here.

Comment: By disabling the use of Asset Library, I was able to specify the same PNG to both iOS versions. Previously, XCode required a different PNG file for each iOS version, even though they were the same.