# adapting to iOS 7 on iPad

Tags: ios, ios7

I need to adapt an app to iOS 7, and I'm having troubles when being run on iPad, since the size of the screen is a little cut off on both bottom and top, as in the image.

[image]

I tried to follow some guidelines (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style/18855464#18855464)) but no luck.

It works on normal iPad 1 on iOS 6 and iPad 2 on both iOS 6 and 7, but it's just in a reduced size (not no cut off images whatsoever).

Could anybody give me some hints please?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with the iPad mini? Your screen shot is for an iPad simulator.

Comment: @rmaddy it's exactly the same in the simulator than in the physical iPad mini

Comment: @noloman Does it work on a normal iPad (2) and retina iPad?

Comment: @rmaddy I edited my answer: It works on normal iPad 1 and 2, but it's just in a reduced size (not no cut off images whatsoever).

Comment: @noloman iPad 1 can't run iOS 6 let alone 7. Did you include any non retina images in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this creating a `boolean` in my Info.plist with the title `View controller-based status bar appearance` and a value `NO`.

Thanks everybody for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As @noloman said: Set the following in your .plist

`View controller-based status bar appearance` (Boolean) to NO

I would suggest this also:
`Status bar is initially hidden` (Boolean) to YES

And call the following within the application when necessary:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

(For example: When a `MPMoviePlayerViewController*` is returning from playing a video (as the status bar is shown))