# status bar issue while presenting model view controller in ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, statusbar, navigationbar

I have returned in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    RootViewController *rvc = [[[RootViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rvc] autorelease];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}

View controller-based status bar appearance  is  YES in plist file
```

when i am pushing view controllers status bar is looking great. As showing in following image.

[image]

but when i am presenting modelviewcontroller it look as following.

[image]

I have written following code in viewDidLoad method of viewcontroller which I am presenting

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    // iOS 7
    navBar.frame = CGRectMake(navBar.frame.origin.x, 20, navBar.frame.size.width, 44);
}
```

I want to display black status bar when presentingmodelview. But it is not displaying.
I tried with

View controller-based status bar appearance  is  NO also in plist file
but it is not working.

My code is working great in all ios version below 7.0 but not in ios 7.0 and above.

Any solution for this ? Let me know if any one not getting my question.

Comment: in iOS 7 default status bar is transparent.

Comment: so you have to take UIImageview with height 20 and set background color Black. and set it delta value -20 in Size inspector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good solution found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style) .

1) Set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO in info.plist (To opt out of having view controllers adjust the status bar style so that we can set the status bar style by using the UIApplicationstatusBarStyle method.)

2) In AppDelegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, call

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);

    self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
}
return YES;
```