# working in iOS 7 but not in iOS 6 - UIView shifted down and creating white space

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, autolayout

I have storyboard as below.

[image]

Here I am giving option as English or Arabic.

When I run on 4s screen (iOS 7), it looks like below.

[image]

When I click on English, I see the scrollView.

[image]

In Appdelegate.m, I have

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if (IS_DEVICE_RUNNING_IOS_7_AND_ABOVE()) {

        NSLog(@"This is iOS 7 iphone...");

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

        NSLog(@"self.window.frame.size.width==%f", self.window.frame.size.width);
        NSLog(@"self.window.frame.size.height==%f", self.window.frame.size.height);

        background = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, 20)];
        background.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [background setHidden:NO];

        self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
        NSLog(@"self.window.frame.size.height==%f", self.window.frame.size.height);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**All this works smoothly**

Now let me run  this on iOS 6, iPhone 4s.

Yuckk!!! All things shift down.

Below is what I see (its ugly, isn't it?)

[image]

***(this image is edited image as the iPhone I am using is mine friend iPhone and I don't want to access his photos :D :P (top status bar is black in iPhone)).***

Any reason why this is happening?

**Note : Autolayout is ON & I want it active** and hence I cannot use [delta part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966372/1066828)

***The problem is not about UIPickerView. The problem is UIView gets shifted down and there is white space. If I click on English, I see UIPickerView at its right place. The only problem is view is getting shifted.***

### Sample project is at [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/va7zn8mgyz4ezm6/ios67Test.zip)

---

### Answer

**I solved it by adding constrains in yellow image**

Comment: Have you tried ios 6/7 deltas?

Comment: @iBhavesh : no, I heard they have problem in 4 inches  (4s) iPhones

Comment: @iBhavesh : I want to have Use Autolayout as active... for some reasons...

Comment: If you have time then study this tutorial it might help you.       http://www.raywenderlich.com/49316/how-to-update-your-app-for-ios-7

Comment: I SOLVED IT BY ADDING CONSTRAINTS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding CONSTRAINTS for yellow image.

This is something weird but it happened to me.