# Remove iOS 7 Status Bar

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios7, statusbar, monogame

I am developing a game for iOS using Monotouch and MonoGame, and I need to make the game full screen, without the status bar.  In iOS 6 this was not a problem, but in iOS 7 I cannot figure out how to disable the status bar.  I have found results on how to do this in Objective-C, but cannot find out how to do it in MonoTouch.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style?rq=1) post says that this is not possible, but the Netflix iOS 7 app has full screen with no status bar (while playing a video).

Comment: Someone down voted this question, if you have some feedback about how I asked the question, please let me know, just down voting it without any feedback isn't helpful to anyone.

Comment: They user didn't ask for code, he asked help to "figure out how", giving references and link for solutions previously tried unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add this to your info.plist before the dict tag

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

example:

```
.....
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```

Comment: This works, as well as my answer above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I figured this out, I don't know if all of these things are necessary to make this work, but this is what I did,

1. I added "Status bar is initially hidden" with boolean value "Yes" to the info.plist
2. I added "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarApp" with boolean value "No" to the info.plist
3. In iOSGameViewController I added:

   ```
   public override bool PrefersStatusBarHidden ()
   {
       return true;
   }
   ```

Now the status bar is not displayed in the game.

Comment: This worked great - the other plist changes were not required for us.