# status bar overlaps with navigation bar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, autolayout, statusbar

I am adding navigation controller through code, in my application. All other thing work fine, but my navigation bar overlaps with the status bar.I have tried by adding

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

but it is not working.

My other controllers in that navigation controller are in xibs only not storyboard.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with the following code (as [suggested by Tacettin Özbölük](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-default-style-in-iphone-app/18966372#18966372)):

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
    addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
    addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.973 green:0.973 blue:0.973 alpha:1]; //change this to match your navigation bar
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want your Navigation Bar to be translucent then use this code and your problem will be solved :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```