# UIStatusBar setTranslucent:NO avoid moving content down

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I am trying to get my `UINavigationBar` and `UIStatusBar` to be opaque and have no translucency properties whatsoever. I tried using `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];` but that moves the view content down a few pixels. I want that content to be under the `UINavigationBar`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you use Autolayout?

Comment: No I don't. I've disabled it for all my ViewControllers.

Comment: If i understood you good, you want on iOS7 move down viewController under statusBar?

Comment: Yes. I want the content to be able to scroll under the UINavigationBar. Like it does on Facebook and Instagram apps. They have opaque navbars. Also, I am trying to achieve the same kind of navbar movement (up/down) they have.

Comment: What's the point of having content underneath the nav bar if it's opaque? The reason your content moves down slightly is so that it's all visible.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I used  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO]; on AppDelegate.m . What worked for me: set "Under Opaque Bars" (see image) property in each ViewController scene under that opaque Navigation Bar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the following properties for your UIViewControllers for elimination pixels shift effect for iOS7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, translucent property just can't be set using `UIAppearance`. Next there is no relation between whether your bars are translucent or opaque & the changed positions of your pixels.

**Customizing the Appearance of a Navigation Bar**

In iOS 7, a navigation bar’s tintColor affects the color of the back indicator image, button titles, and button images. The barTintColor property affects the color of the bar itself. Additionally, navigation bars are translucent by default. Turning the translucency off or on does not affect buttons, since they do not have backgrounds.

Comment: This seems to be referring to the subviews of the navigation bar itself. I am talking about the actual content of the UIViewController. The content gets pushed down by around 64 pixels when the setTranslucent:NO method is called on the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

In my IOS app, I need to do the following in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` function

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);

    //Added on 19th Sep 2013
    self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
}
```

There is a more detailed discussions here [ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style/)