# make status bar translucent - swift

Tags: swift

i want to make the status bar translucent so that the it wont differ with the background image in app

i tried with this code

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

but it makes the status bar as white [image]

i need the status bar but it should be translucent.

for navigation bar i used this in didload

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false      // Show navigationbar.

    self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true        // To add back button.

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem!.title = ""  // set nav bar title

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "" //set back button text


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0 / 255.0, green: 94 / 255.0, blue: 245 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    //        setting navigation bar translucent background need 3 lines of code

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

any guess i am using simulator.

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the status bar?

Comment: no @JohnGool  i need the status bar things and it should be translucent so that the blue background will be visible

Comment: Do want the text color of the status bar white and the background of the status bar color to be translucent?

Comment: Have you defined the View controller-based status in the Info.plist?

Comment: @JohnGool  i need custom status bar so that i make translucent in one page and default at some page

Comment: Why don't you make the status bar white? Then it will show up on every view controller

Comment: its changes the ui look for this screen because the background looks different from the navigation(translucent) along with status bar

Comment: Just to clarify, all of the code used is in your question?

Comment: Did you check this answer and the associated question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18855464/433373

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Autolayout:

Add a constraint for the background image which aligns the background with a constant of -20 to the top of the container view:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Find this steps:

```
1. Select Navigation bar from  Navigation Controller
2. Open Attribute inspector for selected navigation bar and set its bar tint as Clear Color
```

Comment: are you embedding view controller in Navigation  controller

Comment: i have a custom navigation controller. and set enable it by`self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false`

Answer (score -3):

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .clear
```