# Black status bar in iOS 9

Tags: ios

I'm trying to get the status bar to be black for my app since it would look a lot better with my content.

Everything I've been reading is I would need:

```
UIView* loadingView;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

and

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle
{

    return UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
}
```

But this results in an entirely white status bar with no text or battery indicator. Possibly because its depreciated? How do I achieve this in iOS 9+?

Comment: You might wanna check this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-default-style-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status bar is transparent in iOS 9.

> But this results in an entirely white status bar with no text or battery indicator

No it doesn't. It results in a transparent status bar containing white text and battery indicator — and you can't see that, because (as I just said) the status bar is transparent, and what's behind the status bar is also white.

> I'm trying to get the status bar to be black for my app

You can't. The status bar is transparent (as I believe I've mentioned). If you want it to *seem* black, put a black view *behind* it.

In other words, the black region behind the status bar, which you think will look good with your content, will need to be *part* of your content.

Comment: Great, I set my view's background to black but now the text and battery indicator are invisible.

Comment: Well, obviously then you _also_ need to ask for light status bar content to contrast with it.

Comment: Ill try that in code then, was requesting it in my project properties.

Comment: Right, there's no such project property. Each view controller must dictate the status bar appearance by implementing `preferredStatusBarStyle`.